# Adding ASCII value to integer using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, ascii

I was working with pointers in C++. The snippet is given below.

```
int i=97;
char c='A', &cp=c;
cp+=i;
printf("%d",cp);`
```

ASCII of 'A' is 65, then cp will become 97 + 32 which is 162.

But the output I'm getting is -94.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Arun AJ  What C compiler are you using? or is it a C++ one?

Comment: This code is C++, not C. `char &` is a reference (not a pointer) which is not available in C.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The code is C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp += i` is like `cp = cp + i;` where `cp + i` sums to 162 and then 162 is assigned to a `char`.

Assigning an out-of-range value to a `char` leads to implementation defined behavior.

In this case the value wrapped by subtracting 256 and assigned -94.

---

Yet this code does not look like C with `char &cp = c;`.  More like C++. Hmmm.

Comment: @ArunAJ Still would like to know: What C compiler are you using? or is it a C++ one?

Comment: Sorry, it is C++. I am using OnlineGDB.

Answer (score -1):

A pointer is a different thing whatever you are considering. A pointer can point to an address and that address can not be assigned by the user as a constant. It can be only the address of any variable. The statement you have given is invalid. Ex.

```
int a=10;
int * b = &a;  // pointing b to a's address 
int * c;       // pointer pointing to nothing
c = &a;        // pointing c to a's address
printf("%d = %d = %d",a, *b, *c);  //pointer value is accessed by *varilable name
*c = 20;       // changing value of a 
printf("%d =%d = %d", a, *b, *c);   // will print 20 =20 = 20
c=20;    //invalid statement because we can not assign address as constant
c=c+1;   // valid statement and increment address by sizeof(int)
```

Comment: If you are using c++ compiler then signed value of 162 (char in 2's complement is -94)